# Ubuntu attempt to read or write outside of disk, entering rescue mode

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

Ubuntu 12 and now Ubuntu 14.10 do not boot, they drop out into grub rescue saying "error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd1'.

I had no problems a couple of years ago with v10 but thought I should upgrade. Maybe I should go back to the old version?

My motherboard (GA-8IPE775-G, CPU is LGA775 Pentium® 4 processor) is several years old if that's anything to do with it. Could it be a problem with 32/64-bit differences? The 32-bit Ubuntu version says for machines with less than 2GB RAM, but I have 2GB and I'm going to get another 2GB.

I have 2x250GB drives for Windows XP, and a separate 60GB drive for Ubuntu. The details from Boot Repair's boot info summary is at [paste.ubuntu.com/8738834](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8738834).

This fixed the problem very temporarily. The grub boot menu appeared, I selected Ubuntu, which then wanted to scan the disks, and then it crashed. I ran Boot Repair again, selected Windows successfully, restarted computer and then it crashed to grub rescue again.

Everything on the computer seems okay, it seems to be grub2 that's the problem. When I run Ubuntu Live CD all the files are installed okay on the 60GB drive.

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Boot the live CD. In the boot-menu there is memtest to test your system. What is the outcome of this test?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also experiencing this with 14.10. It seems to be the latest kernel i believe that is causing this as prior to updating it everything was functioning correctly. Also did a reinstall of 14.04 and everything worked as intended then did live upgrade to 14.10 and issue reappears. Another thing I noticed was that when I fdisk the drive that Ubuntu is installed on it complaons of being past sector limit or something along those lines for the extended partition. I'm about to do another 14.04 reinstall and see if issue reespears.